# Finding files from Windows Volume GUID Name Paths in Node.js

Tags: node.js, glob

I have several paths in format "\?\Volume{56D4B0E2-0000-0000-0000-00A861000000}\dir1" and I need to find and read JSON files from the paths.

glob doesn't seem to find anything from those paths.

```
glob(rootDir + '\\**\\*.json', {}, (err, files) => {
  ...
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or does glob not support "\?\Volume{}" paths?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use node fs and path instead of glob:

```
static getFilesFromPath(path, extension) {
  let dir = fs.readdirSync( path );
  return dir.filter( elm => elm.match(new RegExp(`.*\.(${extension})`, 'ig')));
}
```